# How to split open all files that have TODO in them in gvim?

Tags: vim

I want to open all my source files, that have TODO in them, in split buffers in gvim.

I am pretty sure that this could be done with a `grep` that pipes its output to the edit command, but I am unsure how to implement this.

Comment: how many files are you talking about? Might be a little impractical to have something like 30 splits on the same screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a feature in vim which probably does what you want far more nicely than what you actually asked for.  Check out `:help quickfix`.  Essentially you can perform your grep as you'd imagine:

`grep -rn TODO . > index.txt`

Then you can open this index in vim's quicklist:

`vim -q index.txt`

This will allow you to navigate through every TODO in all those files by doing `:cn` (next) and `:cp` (previous).  It's also possible to `:copen` which opens the quicklist window at the bottom showing you where you are in the entire list and allowing you to navigate to each TODO in any file.

Comment: Creating a file seems unnecessarily messy. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984648/1450294

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't  open them  in splits,  unless you know  that there  are only  two or
three. But  if there  are only  two or  three files  to be  edited, why  are you
looking for a command to automate opening them, after all?

This is the basic grep you can use:

```
grep -lIr TODO .
```

It searches  the current directory  recursively for files containing  `TODO` and
list them. It also avoid matching  binary files (including .swp and .swo files).
Then, if you're running a GUI Vim, I'd go with:

```
mvim --remote-silent $(grep -lIr TODO .)
```

Or, within  Vim, you can  use the `:argadd`  command and backticks  expansion as
cleverly suggested by sehe in the comments:

```
:args `grep -Ilr TODO .`
```

Comment: tr can also be `paste -sd' '`

Comment: You can just `:args \`grep -Ilr TODO .\`` (to immediately open/show them all, `:sall` or `:tab sall` etc.)

Comment: @sehe Hmm, why simplify if you can complicate? :-) I didn't remember about using the backticks in this case, and the string evaluated with newlines wouldn't play well with :exec, so I came up with the pipe to tr.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xargs`:

```
grep -l TODO * | xargs vim -o
```

Comment: this has a tendency to mess up the terminal since vim runs in a subshell, not connected to the terminal. At least, use `xargs gvim -o` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated which operating system and shell you're using. But assuming you're using something `bash`-like, this should work:

`vim -o $(grep -lr TODO .)`

Be careful if your current working directory is a git repo or something, though, because this will include files in there. And depending on how you have vim set up, you might get old swap files, too. To work around this, I have an [`alias`](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) to `grep`, with a buncho' `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` arguments. e.g:

`alias gg='grep --exclude='\''*.sw?'\'' --exclude-dir='\'.git\'`